# Connect docker container from another container and from localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple web app which I configured to run in docker containers. The configuration looks like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  service-1:
    build: service-1
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - uni

  service-1-postgres:
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    image: "postgres:11.3"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - uni

networks:
  uni:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.0.1/24
```

I connect to my postgres container inside another container using 192.168.0.1(network subnet). But now I want to be able to run my service from IDE for faster development, and db in container. But now connection to db fails. How I can configure my docker-compose to have an ability to connect to my db container inside network and outside it(from db) using the same host.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to have some kind of actual configuration for this.  The C PostgreSQL client library supports a standard `PGHOST` environment variable which is a good option.

In your local-development IDE setup, you can set `PGHOST=localhost` or leave it unset.  It will connect to localhost (from the host's point of view) port 5432, and port 5432 on the host is what you've set the published port for your PostgreSQL container.

Conversely, when you're running this in Docker, you can set `PGHOST` to the other container's name, provided both containers are on the same non-default network.  Docker Compose will create a non-default network automatically for you and you don't need the manual network configuration you show.  Containers are reachable using the name of their service block as hostnames.

```
version: '3'
services:
  service-1:
    build: service-1
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      PGHOST: service-1-postgres

  service-1-postgres:
    # as above, less the networks: block
```